# Pandas concat not concatenating, but appending

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, concatenation

I'm hoping for some help.
I am trying to concatenate three dataframes in pandas with a multiindex. Two of them work fine, but the third keeps appending, instead of concatenating.
They all have the same multiindex (I have tested this by df1.index.name == df2.index.name)

This is what I have tried:

```
df_final = pd.concat([df1, df2], axis = 1)
```

example:

```
df1
A   B    X
0   1    3
    2    4

df2
A   B    Y
0   1    20
    2    30
```

What I want to get is this:

```
df_final
A   B    X    Y
0   1    3    20
    2    4    30
```

But what I keep getting is this:

```
df_final
A   B    X    Y
0   1    3    NaN
    2    4    NaN
0   1    NaN  20
    2    NaN  30
```

Any ideas? I have also tried

```
df_final = pd.concat([df1, df2], axis = 1, keys = ['A', 'B'])
```

But then df2 doesn't appear at all.

Thanks!

Comment: I think in that case, you can use merge() instead.

Comment: can you please attach code to reproduce your input dataframes?

Comment: For this purpose you should use merge or join, please take a look at https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/merging.html

Answer (score 2):

**First way** (and the better one in this case):

use merge:

```
pd.merge(left=df1, right=df2, on=['A','B'], how='inner')
```

**Second way**:

If you prefer using concat you can use groupby after it:

```
df_final = pd.concat([df1, df2])
df_final = df_final.groupby(['A','B']).first()
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you everyone for your help!
With your suggestions, I tried merging, but I got a new error:

ValueError: You are trying to merge on int64 and object columns. If you wish to proceed you should use pd.concat

Which led me to find that one of the indexes in the dataframe that was appending was an object instead of an integer. So I've changed that and now the concat works!

This has taken me days to get through...
So thank you again!

Answer (score 0):

Try doing

```
pd.merge(df1, df2)
```

join() may also be used for your problem, provided you add the 'key' column to all your dataframes.